# Cannot center Java Applet in HTML file

Tags: html, css, applet, center, margin

I need to center my applet horizontally AND vertically but I can only center it horizontally. Can any one help with this simple CSS problem? I have tried using "display: inline-block;" and "display: block;" but both of this has no effect. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testing..</title>    
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #container {
                width: 640px;
                height: 610px;              
                margin: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <applet code="TetrisApplet.class" width="640" height="610"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same width of div and applet
or put applet into new div width display:inline-block;

Comment: Thanks, I got it centered horizontally, now its stuck at the top. I just need to center it vertically now. That helped :)

Comment: 6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: Thanks, only the "Absolute Positioning and Negative Margin" method worked :)